# "There are no staged changes to commit" dialog box

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I have no staged changes, and I try to commit, I get the following dialog box:

[image]

If I choose **Always**, will unstaged changes be auto-committed in the future only if there are no staged changes? Or even if there are some staged changes?

Comment: I didn't know there was an option to turn that off!

Comment: what's meaning of "staged changes" ?

Comment: @vikramvi You can select a number of files to mark as "staged", and when you next commit, only those files will be committed. See [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/119782/100120), the [relevant section of the Git Book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Recording-Changes-to-the-Repository).

Comment: My answer to this is always NO!  I hate that it is even suggested.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When there are no staged changes.

You can check it for yourself and disable at any moment from `settings.json`

```javascript
// Commit all changes when there are no staged changes.
"git.enableSmartCommit": false,
```

Answer (score 17):

[image]

[image]

in the list of CHANGES list, click the plus icon button on right side to make item to be staged.

Comment: And this has nothing to do with the question, which is specifically about the dialog box, and the consequences of choosing **Always**.

Comment: I just want to tell you the concept of git STAGED changes and other changes. got it?

Comment: As an explanation for staging vs commitingt in git, a screenshot of the Visual Studio Code UI leaves much to be desired. But note: the question is **not about staging vs committing in git**, nor even about **staging and committing within VS Code**; it is about the unclear (in my opinion) wording of a specific dialog box, and the effects of choosing one option over the other in said dialog box. Your answer still has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: Having a slightly different question than the original, this answer explained things fare more clearly and in general.

Comment: @typhon04 _Having a slightly different question than the original, this answer explained things fare more clearly and in general._ That is not a good thing. If someone is looking for the answer to the **original question**, this answer however clear it may be is pretty much useless. And unless the question to be answered is _How do I interpret the VS Code UI for working with Git?_, the answer is also profoundly useless -- it doesn't describe the difference between stage and commit, and the text embedded in the image is not searchable.

Comment: _I just want to tell you the concept of git STAGED changes and other changes._ You haven't explained what staging is, and why it might be useful. All you've done is posted a screenshot with two lists of items, saying only that one list is staged and will be committed, and the other will not be committed.